# Magento - addAttributeToSelect for multiple fields not working

Tags: magento

I am trying to get the user orders history, used the following query and its working fine. But its returning all the order related fields from table

```
    $collection     = Mage::getModel("sales/order")->getCollection()
                               ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                               ->addFieldToFilter('customer_id', 400)
                               ->setOrder('created_at', 'desc');
```

I want to fetch only particular fields, so in case of **->addAttributeToSelect('*')**

```
     used the following code 

 ->addAttributeToSelect(array('created_at','customer_id','increment_id','updated_at','status','entity_id','state'))
```

But getting error as **"Cannot determine the field name."**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `addFieldToSelect`
I got the output